# Add system apps in a custom rom

Tags: custom-roms, rom-flashing

I'm trying to change a few some system apps in an already working custom rom (Lewa Os - CM7 derived) and my device is an Acer Liquid Metal)

Lewa Os is a chinese rom that I've translated thanks to the help of other guys in the forum to Italian.

So I want to repack the rom with all the new Italian files (framework-res.apk, phone.apk and so on).

I've used xda's kitchen (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=633246) and following all the simple wizard (I didn't modify a thing) I simply added with copy and paste the new apks in the folder and cooked the rom.

When I flash it the final result is a rom that has everything BUT the "new" apks.

What's wrong?

How can I find it out?

Comment: You should mention the Device so that people understand better.

Comment: Device added: thx!

Answer (score 1):

If just for your phone - you can simply put files manually via root explorer, reset permissions and reboot.

Comment: I know this but I want to cook a rom for the other to install easily :)

Comment: I've already prepared a zip that can be flashed without problems but I'll love to have a single rom to flash.

Answer (score 0):

Place you apks in `system/app/`
framework-res.apk goes into `system/framework/`
Remove those apks which yours' are replacing. Now you can use the kitchen to cook your rom and then flash away :)
Make sure that the apks don't have spaces in their filename. They should be flashed without issues.

Comment: I'm trying it right now! The only thing I didn't do was removing the files (I just overwrote) but I am gonna do this now. Other options? I can choose simply "Lazy mode" from the kitchen? Thx! :)

Comment: You don't need the kitchen if you're not using any of the options. You could just zip up the boot.img system META-INF with normal compression.

Comment: No luck :(
Here's the log: http://pastebin.com/CS7ADW0C

Comment: Ah! So I just unzip / rezip? I'll do it now.

Comment: No way :'( I really don't know what could be. If I prepare a single zip file with the apks in it is perfect. If I make a complete rom it won't work. :(

Comment: Can't help without seeing the files.. :(

Comment: If you want I can show you the whole process with some desktop sharing...

Comment: teamviewer? BTW even my device shares the same chipset including the gpu

Comment: sure! 246533733 - 1916

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6488/discussion-between-pitto-and-varunyellina)